# Access HiddenFor(Model=>Model.Id)  MVC ASP.NET in Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How do I access the following written in View

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(Model=>Model.id)
```

in Controller
  ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Action method that takes the Type that you used as Model in your view.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(MyModel model)
{
   var id = model.id;//the id in @Html.HiddenFor(Model=>Model.id)
}
```